# C Language -> Separate words from a paragraph

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, realloc, strtok

My function save_words receives armazena and size. Armazena is a dynamic array which contains paragraphs, and size it's the size of the array. In this function i want to put word to word in other dynamic array called words. When i run it, it crashes. 
I appreciate your help.

```
char **save_words(char **armazena, int *size)
{
    char *token = NULL;
    char** armazena_aux = armazena;
    int i, count=0;
    char **words = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*(10));
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        token = strtok(*(armazena+i)," .?!,");
        while( token != NULL )
        {
            int tam = strlen(token);
            armazena[count] = (char*) malloc(tam+2);
            strcpy(armazena[count],token);
            armazena[count][tam+1]='\0';
            count++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " .?!,");

            if (count%10==0)
            {
                words = realloc(words, sizeof(char*)*(count + 10));
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: "it crashes" - use a debugger.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<size; i++)` ?? Mind that `size` is a pointer to `int`..

Comment: The problem might be in the code that is calling `save_words`.

Comment: Maybe "armazena" is a read-only location and strtok messes it up. This would be why const correctness is important.

Comment: change to `char **words = malloc(sizeof(char*)*size)`

Answer (score 0):

Is `armazena[count] = (char*) malloc(tam+2);` what you want?  I would have thought `words[count] = ...;`.  The first time through the outer loop is ok, because you hoist armazena[0] into strtok, but if it contains more than one word, your second time through the outer loop will be processing strings generated from the first time.
Worse, if that first string contained more words than the armazena vector can accommodate, you will be corrupting something...